# Outlook add-in not showing in shared mailbox

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am trying to see how add-ins work for the first time now, and according to the documentation it should be possible to view the add-in inside my shared mailbox.
For some reason it doesn't seem to work, is this because I'm running the add-in locally?

I can say that I am able to support the latest version, so that's not a problem.
So far, the only thing I did was create the outlook add-in tutorial and added the changes for the support mailbox, so nothing special is happening right now.

Any ideas what the problem might be?

Thanks in advance!

Billy Cottrell

## UPDATE 1:

This outlook add-in is mainly built for Outlook app for Windows, which comes as part of the Office 365 package.

The Outlook version im using is a recent one: Version 2302 build 16130.20218

As I mentioned before, the code is nothing special and can be reproduced by following the outlook add-in tutorial using the yeoman generator:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/outlook-quickstart?tabs=yeomangenerator

The only change I have made is to the manifest, which is according to the documentation to allow the add-in to be used within a shared mailbox: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/delegate-access?tabs=windows%2Cxmlmanifest#configure-the-manifest

So only the permission element was updated and the Supportsharedfolder was added and set to true.

Hope this information helps!

Manifest:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<OfficeApp xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0"
  xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.0"
  xsi:type="MailApp">
  <Id>01d67f6d-b061-4c40-9851-85106bdef930</Id>
  <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>Contoso</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="My Office Add-in" />
  <Description DefaultValue="A template to get started." />
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-64.png" />
  <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-128.png" />
  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="https://www.contoso.com/help" />
  <AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>https://www.contoso.com</AppDomain>
  </AppDomains>
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Mailbox" />
  </Hosts>
  <Requirements>
    <Sets>
      <Set Name="Mailbox" MinVersion="1.1" />
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>
  <FormSettings>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemRead">
      <DesktopSettings>
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html" />
        <RequestedHeight>250</RequestedHeight>
      </DesktopSettings>
    </Form>
  </FormSettings>
  <Permissions>ReadWriteMailbox</Permissions>
  <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
    <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Read" />
  </Rule>
  <DisableEntityHighlighting>false</DisableEntityHighlighting>
  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides"
    xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
    <Requirements>
      <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.3">
        <bt:Set Name="Mailbox" />
      </bt:Sets>
    </Requirements>
    <Hosts>
      <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
        <DesktopFormFactor>
          <SupportsSharedFolders>true</SupportsSharedFolders>
          <FunctionFile resid="Commands.Url" />
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
            <OfficeTab id="TabDefault">
              <Group id="msgReadGroup">
                <Label resid="GroupLabel" />
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="msgReadOpenPaneButton">
                  <Label resid="TaskpaneButton.Label" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="TaskpaneButton.Label" />
                    <Description resid="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                    <SourceLocation resid="Taskpane.Url" />
                  </Action>
                </Control>
                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="ActionButton">
                  <Label resid="ActionButton.Label" />
                  <Supertip>
                    <Title resid="ActionButton.Label" />
                    <Description resid="ActionButton.Tooltip" />
                  </Supertip>
                  <Icon>
                    <bt:Image size="16" resid="Icon.16x16" />
                    <bt:Image size="32" resid="Icon.32x32" />
                    <bt:Image size="80" resid="Icon.80x80" />
                  </Icon>
                  <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
                    <FunctionName>action</FunctionName>
                  </Action>
                </Control>
              </Group>
            </OfficeTab>
          </ExtensionPoint>
        </DesktopFormFactor>
      </Host>
    </Hosts>
    <Resources>
      <bt:Images>
        <bt:Image id="Icon.16x16" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-16.png" />
        <bt:Image id="Icon.32x32" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-32.png" />
        <bt:Image id="Icon.80x80" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/assets/icon-80.png" />
      </bt:Images>
      <bt:Urls>
        <bt:Url id="Commands.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/commands.html" />
        <bt:Url id="Taskpane.Url" DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html" />
      </bt:Urls>
      <bt:ShortStrings>
        <bt:String id="GroupLabel" DefaultValue="Contoso Add-in" />
        <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Label" DefaultValue="Show Taskpane" />
        <bt:String id="ActionButton.Label" DefaultValue="Perform an action" />
      </bt:ShortStrings>
      <bt:LongStrings>
        <bt:String id="TaskpaneButton.Tooltip"
          DefaultValue="Opens a pane displaying all available properties." />
        <bt:String id="ActionButton.Tooltip" DefaultValue="Perform an action when clicked." />
      </bt:LongStrings>
    </Resources>
  </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

## UPDATE 2:

Updating the requirement set to a more recent version 1.12 didn't work...

Comment: Do you develop an Outlook web add-in? How does your manifest look like? Could you be more specific? What is your current Outlook version?

Comment: Where do you expect to see your add-in for shared mailboxes?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev well If I open a mail in my own mailbox it appears at the top in the ribbon, but when I go to a shared mailbox I see it appear for a second and it disappears immediately.

Comment: It makes sense to share your manifest.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev I have added manifest, but then again as I mentioned it's almost the default manifest + the changes for the shared mailbox, nothing else. So I don't think It's that useful to share it anyways.

Comment: Have you tried to set a proper requirement set in the manifest?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev no... because I have no clue how I should configure it in the first place to make it work correctly. Since I just followed the tutorial and there was no message about updating the requirement set, neither was there for the shared mailbox. So I have no clue what the influence is when changing the requirement set, or why I should change it in the first place.

Comment: See [Enable shared folders and shared mailbox scenarios in an Outlook add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/delegate-access?tabs=windows)

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev I changed the requirement version to 1.8 and even to 1.12 yet it doesn't seem to work for my shared mailbox? Is it because im running it locally?

Comment: @BillyCottrell, your manifest snippet above is using VersionOverridesV1_0. You need VersionOverridesV1_1. Not sure if you have already tried that or not. If not, see the example in Eugene's answer.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT adding the extra VersionOverrides is what fixed it, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the manifest file you need to set the `SupportsSharedFolders` element to true under the parent element `DesktopFormFactor`.

```
...
<VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
  <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1" xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">
    ...
    <Hosts>
      <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
        <DesktopFormFactor>
          <SupportsSharedFolders>true</SupportsSharedFolders>
          <FunctionFile resid="residDesktopFuncUrl" />
          <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
            <!-- configure selected extension point -->
          </ExtensionPoint>

          <!-- You can define more than one ExtensionPoint element as needed -->

        </DesktopFormFactor>
      </Host>
    </Hosts>
    ...
  </VersionOverrides>
</VersionOverrides>
...
```

You can get an item's shared properties in `Compose` or `Read` mode by calling the `item.getSharedPropertiesAsync` method. This returns a `SharedProperties` object that currently provides the user's permissions, the owner's email address, the REST API's base URL, and the target mailbox.

See [Enable shared folders and shared mailbox scenarios in an Outlook add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/delegate-access?tabs=windows%2Cxmlmanifest) for more information and versions of client applications that support this feature.

Support for this feature was introduced in [requirement set 1.8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/requirement-sets/outlook/requirement-set-1.8/outlook-requirement-set-1.8) (for details, refer to [clients and platforms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/requirement-sets/outlook/outlook-api-requirement-sets#requirement-sets-supported-by-exchange-servers-and-outlook-clients)).

Comment: It appears that adding the extra version overrides is necessary, as this fixed the issue!